# Merge [asp-net-core-mvc-2.0] with [asp.net-core-mvc-2.0]

Tags: discussion, tags

It seems that someone introduced [asp-net-core-mvc-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp-net-core-mvc-2.0) instead of using the pattern of ASP.NET => [asp.net-core-mvc-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core-mvc-2.0), can we merge these?

Comment: Well, maybe the problem is that [asp.net-core-mvc-2.0] [isn't even suggested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oGo5.png).

Comment: @aaron All asp.net tags start with asp.net... In fact, all of the tags in your screenshot are bad

Comment: I tried dong a synonym, but because `asp-net...` has more it wouldn't allow me to. I've been gradually editing those bad tags out to tip the balance and maybe then get the suggestion to be accepted. When ever you have time you could edit some as I've been doing it on my own for a wile now.

Comment: As of this comment I am down to 170 posts left.

Comment: It is below 100 now. Thanks. Tried again but a while back when I had thought I was merging them it ended up with a reverse synonym. so now that I try to do the correct one it is not allowing the suggestion. Will see if I can get the original suggestion removed.

Comment: @Nkosi I'm at work so I will be helping slowly. It's down to 90 now!

Comment: I create a request to see if I can get the reverse synonym suggestion removed https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362812/please-remove-suggested-synonym-asp-net-core-mvc-2-0-to-asp-net-core-mvc-2-0

Comment: All questions removed. Still need to get suggestion reversed though. Can you vote it down and I'll see if I can find some one else to help. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/asp-net-core-mvc-2.0/synonyms

Comment: Cannot vote down because of the missing reputation on that tag, unfortunately

Comment: Yeah only just realized the catch 22. Live and learn I guess. lol

Comment: Mod dealt with the tag. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be considered done, tag doesn't exist anymore.