# Please remove suggested synonym [asp.net-core-mvc-2.0] to [asp-net-core-mvc-2.0]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

Please remove the suggested synonym for the [asp.net-core-mvc-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core-mvc-2.0) tag from the [asp-net-core-mvc-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp-net-core-mvc-2.0) tag [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/asp-net-core-mvc-2.0/synonyms) so that the correct suggestion can be made.

It was done in the incorrect direction and should be reversed.

If you go to https://stackoverflow.com/tags/asp-net-core-mvc-2.0/synonyms and down-vote the suggestion, then it should get deleted.

According to the instructions there

> Users with more than 2500 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms. Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can vote for tag synonyms. Suggestions will be automatically approved when they reach a score of 4, **and automatically deleted when they reach a score of -2.**

Currently editing questions with [asp-net-core-mvc-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp-net-core-mvc-2.0) to allow the correct suggestion, but it won't work with the reverse synonym suggestion already made.

UPDATE:

Well, chalk it up to a learning experience. With some assistance I was able to retag the offending question only to realize after the fact that I would have needed users with rep on that specific tag to vote it down to have it removed.

At this point I guess only a moderator can help with this issue.

Comment: Notice that the effort to re-tag [tag:asp-net-core-mvc-2.0] to [tag:asp.net-core-mvc-2.0] is being followed [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361529/merge-asp-net-core-mvc-2-0-with-asp-net-core-mvc-2-0?noredirect=1#comment553850_361529)

Comment: @ArunVinoth It's not a duplicate, they are different requests

Comment: actually Mods can retag all the questions if we justify, merge all the tags & keep the final one which you want to keep..

Comment: Synonym removed and empty tag destroyed...

Comment: @animuson the problem with what you did is [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/362739/7920473) in future

Comment: @animuson Would you be so kind as to add the [meta-tag:status-completed] tag?

Comment: I actually think `asp.net-core-mvc-2.0` shouldn’t even exist. With ASP.NET Core, there isn’t really much a difference between ASP.NET Core and ASP.NET Core MVC, compared to how it was with ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC. MVC is kind of built-in into Core, and is generally bound by the version of ASP.NET Core. So this should probably just be `asp.net-core-2.0` without any MVC (or *just maybe* with `asp.net-core-mvc`)

Comment: @poke I agree with having just the `asp.net-core-2.0` or  `asp.net-core-mvc`. You think a synonym should be suggested?

Comment: Yeah, I think that would make the most sense. I tried suggesting `asp.net-core-mvc-2.0` as a synonym for `asp.net-core-mvc` but it told me that version specific synonyms can only be made by moderators. – animuson, could you take care of that?